# How to color points base on other values in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, data-visualization, matplotlib-basemap

I have some data that looks like this: (4,120,507.0),(6, 37, 7012.0),etc

The first two is the coordinates, another is the values. I've drawn a scatter plot based on these coordinates.

So how can I color these points based on the values? the bigger the values is ,the darker the color? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a scatter plot, the `c` argument to `plt.scatter(x,y,c=z)` can be set to determine the color depending on the value of `z`. The color is set according to a [colormap](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html), which can be set with the `cmap` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [(4,120,507.0),(5, 80, 5415.0),(6, 37, 7012.0),(7, 96, 2173.0),(8,57,3777.0)]
x,y,z = zip(*a)

plt.scatter(x,y, c=z, s=100, cmap="YlOrBr", edgecolor="k")
plt.colorbar(label="values")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Also refer to the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter) and look at the [matplotlib examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html).